# Codeigniter 3.0 + Community Auth + HMVC modular extension = The configuration file login.php does not exist

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

As described in the title, I got "The configuration file login.php does not exist" when trying to login using community auth library

This link of HMVC extension i use :
[HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads)

Comunnity Auth library : [Community Auth](https://bitbucket.org/skunkbad/community-auth-for-codeigniter-3/overview)

> because I didnt know the error location, this is my code [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3VR3KatX1lZR2oxTzZ2VEd3dEU/view?usp=sharing)
>   , you only need to import ciauth.sql and reconfigure application/config/database.php

please ask if my question is still unclear, because english is not my first language

Thanks^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution with hint given by Ken Cheung.

I simply move login.php file from application/third_party/community_auth/config/form_validation/auth/

TO

application/config/

Answer (score 2):

In third_party/community_auth/libraries/Authentication.php it loads:

```
$this->CI->config->load( 'form_validation/auth/login' );
```

But there's no config/form_validation/auth/login.php under the application/ folder.

Comment: KenCheung ,then why if i remove MY_Loader and MY_router from application/core (which mean remove HMVC extension), the login process run fine?

Comment: ,i try to copy config/form_validation/auth/login.php and paste in application/config and still return the same error